# Express: getting two values from req.params.id, one is what I need, the other is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I'm using Express and Pug and I am able to pass the ID of a document from MongoDB into the URL successfully.

Here is what I'm using for Pug code if it helps:

```
-var url = service.id
a(href="/service/" + url)

http://localhost:3000/service/5a7b340af018ca044a7b3a7b //the correct URL
```

I am also able to get the id using a standard app.get function and pass it into the MongoDB using Mongoose, which does return what I want... at first.

```
app.get('/service/:sid', (req, res) => {
Services.findOne({ _id: req.params.sid }).exec(function(err, post) {
res.render('service.pug');
```

But it appears that the value for req.params.sid is almost immediately overridden by a second value, which is undefined. When I console.log I keep getting two values, one right after the other:

```
console.log(req.params.sid);
5a7b340af018ca044a7b3a7b // the value I want
undefined // the value that ends up overriding the id I need.
```

I've done everything I can think of to get rid of the second, overriding value but nothing works.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed there are no other requests going to `/service/:sid`?

Comment: I'd suggest you add a `console.log(req.url)` to your handler and find out what URL is hitting your route (probably `/service`) and then find out where in your browser page that is coming from.  If you show us the entire route handler, we can see if there's an asynchronous programming mistake there.

Comment: Ha! I don't believe it. I turned it off and walked away then started nodemon back up to console.log(req.url) and it's working perfectly! I've been at this stupid problem all day and all I had to do was turn nodemon off and back on... Not sure why that happened but thanks anyway for the quick comments.

Comment: @tWoolsey What makes you think that req.params.sid has been overridden ? show us the entire get method to see what is going there

Comment: @YouneL I watched it happen through console.log(req.params.sid). It's not happening now but console.log(req.params) would return two objects the first being the id, the second being undefined, both typeof String. The console.log showed the first, correct mongodb id and then a second later it would log "undefined." This had an effect on the pug template as the HTML would render with all of the values pulled from the database using the id. When you tried to access the same exact values after the page rendered it would say "cannot read 'foo' of undefined.